# Python: print incomplete

Tags: python, list, sorting, printing

I have the following problem.
I created the following list:

```
usinlist = [['strawberries',    2.05,   'rosales'],
            ['pineapples',      2.05,   'poales'],
            ['bananas',         2.05,   'zingiberales'],
            ['oranges',         2.05,   'sapindales'],
            ['apples',          2.05,   'rosales'],
            ['broccoli',        2.05,   'rosales'],
            ['cauliflower',     2.05,   'rosales'],
            ['cucumber',        2.05,   'cucurbitales'],
            ['lettuce',         2.05,   'asterales'],
            ['sprouts',         2.05,   'rosales']]
```

I need to print this list and sort it alphabetically using the 3 element usinlist[x][x][2].
The code I have now to sort is the following:

```
print('\n'.join('{}: {}'.format(*k) for k in sorted(usinlist, key=lambda k: (k[2], k[0], k[1]))))
```

After sorting the kind/type[2] on alphabetical order, it sort the fruit/vegetable names on alphabetical order, but the problem that occurs is that the it does sort, but doesn't print the list complete.

The output is as following:

```
lettuce: 2.05
cucumber: 2.05
pineapples: 2.05
apples: 2.05
broccoli: 2.05
cauliflower: 2.05
sprouts: 2.05
strawberries: 2.05
oranges: 2.05
bananas: 2.05
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong here :) ?

Comment: you can use `key=itemgetter(2, 0, 1)` instead of the lambda. `itemgetter` is in the `operator` module

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have only two placeholders in your format string. Try using

```
print('\n'.join('{}: {} ({})'.format(*k) for k in sorted(usinlist, key=lambda k: (k[2], k[0], k[1]))))
```

or whatever format you need.

Comment: Glad to help, rolling.

Answer (score 1):

And this?:

```
print('\n'.join('{}: {}: {}'.format(*k) for k in sorted(usinlist, key=lambda k: (k[2], k[0], k[1]))))
```